# Is chompack not suitable for windows 64 bit machine?

Tags: python-2.7, cvxopt

I have installed python, cython, cvxopt but failed to install chompack. The error message is Cython does not appear to be installed. But Cython is stalled as when I try to install it says requirement already satisfied. Any suggestion? My machine is windows 64 bit.